# How to convert and use struct c++ to c# using dllImport?

Tags: c#, c++, struct, dllimport, handle

I have tried using `DLLImport` to call a C++ method.
This is the declaration of functions in C++:

`DWORD GetReaderHandle (Handle *handle);

    INT GetScanData (INT *count,SCN_ETQ *ScanDataBuf);
    INT ReadByaTe (BYTE *Password,BYTE*aTe,INT aTeLen,INT mr,BYTE *data,INT DataLen);`

    `struct SCN_ETQ
    {
    int aTeLen;
    byte ATEBuffer[256];
    };`

Please tell me how I can convert this to c#.
How can I initialize struct `SCN_ETQ` to use it in main?
Please, I need help!

Comment: You need to use Interop Services for this.  That much you might already know.  Unfortunately, there is more to it because C++ does what is commonly called name mangling.  So the method names you see in the C++ source code are not necessarily the same when you try to call them in the DLL from C#.  You have to take steps to account for C++ doing this.  I am short of time which is why the comment rather than a full answer.  I will check back later though.

Comment: Yes i have secesefly import the dll im my program ; using System.Runtime.InteropServices
[DllImport(@"Program Files\\SCANCode.dll")]private  static extern int GetReaderHandle( IntPtr handle);

Comment: and i declarte the struct like this : [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
         public struct SCN_ETQ
        {
            public int aTeLen; // lenth
            public byte[] ATEBuffer; // data
         };

Comment: but for the other fonctions , i don't how to declarte and use them !?! Help please.. i'am a beginner.best regrads

Comment: [edit] your answer to include the information in your comments, or even better include a [mcve]. While you're at it remove the begging, it's noise that distracts from the question.